# How can I get back the main character from the UTF-8 code in JAVA?

Tags: java, utf-8, ascii, decode, emoji

I am making an ASCII Encoder-Decoder. I am encoding the characters into UTF-8. To encode I am using this code:

```
private String asciiReturn(String inpString){
int codePoint = 0;
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < inpString.length(); i++){
codePoint = Character.codePointAt(inpString, i);
i += Character.charCount(codePoint) - 1;
str.append(codePoint);
str.append(" ");
}
return str.toString();
}
```

So by this, I can encode all those emoji characters too.

Like '‍♂️' for this emoji I am getting "129335 127995 8205 9794 65039". So this is basically the UTF-8 decimal value of the emoji and that's exactly what I want. But my problem is the decoding.

What I want is: (Example)

Input String: "72 117 104 33 129335 127995 8205 9794 65039"
Output String: "Huh!‍♂️"

Cause:
72 -> 'H'
117 -> 'u'
104 -> 'h'
33 -> '!'
129335 127995 8205 9794 65039 -> '‍♂️'

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to split by space, parse each integer and then use StringBuilder::appendCodePoint method. Give it a try and if it not working someone will help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with 'extended ASCII'. Extended ASCII is the set of single byte character sets that have ASCII as byte 0 - 127. None of the extended ASCII character sets support emoji. In any case, you need to put in some effort: what have you tried, and where are you stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
private String decode(String inpString) {
    return Arrays.stream(inpString.split("\\s+"))
        .map(s -> Character.toString(Integer.parseInt(s)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

and

```
String input = "72 117 104 33 129335 127995 8205 9794 65039";
System.out.println(decode(input));
```

output

```
Huh!‍♂️
```

You can also write your encoding method like this:

```
static String asciiReturn(String s) {
    return s.codePoints()
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

and

```
String s = "Huh!‍♂️";
System.out.println(asciiReturn(s));
```

output

```
72 117 104 33 129335 127995 8205 9794 65039
```

Comment: WOW!! It worked, Thank You, very much...just one more request Please, sir...
"Please explain what is actually happening in the split function?"

Comment: `.split("\\s+")` splits a string with spaces and stores it in an array of strings. `\\s+` is a regular expression that represents one or more consecutive spaces.